# Downloading a file from a S3 Server using TPYO's PHP Class

Tags: php, amazon-s3, download, bucket

So, here's what I want to do:

I want to use TPYO's (Undesigned) [Amazon S3 Class](https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class/blob/master/example.php) to get a file from my S3 Bucket, and download it. I'm having **alot** of trouble getting it to work.

I'm using this code, but it's not working for me for some reason:

```
    if ($s3->copyObject($bucketName, $filename, $bucketName, $filename, "public-read", array(), array("Content-Type" => "application/octet-stream", "Content-Disposition" => "attachment"))) {  
         // Successful
    } else {
        // Failed
    }
```

I tried using any other questions, but I couldn't manage to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

I found a way of doing it. I basically dismissed the whole idea of using TPYO's S3 PHP class to download a file from my bucket server. So instead, what I did was I made my bucket's stream an octet-stream, and made any files accessible via URL.

Thanks,
Tom.